# Как вывести весь вводимый текст пользователем из input после определённого слова

Tags: javascript

К примеру, у меня есть input и кнопка, мне нужно, после нажатия на кнопку делать проверку, если в поле ввода после слов "Привет", есть ещё какой-то текст, к примеру "Привет как дела", то при нажатии на кнопку выводить всё после "Привет", как итог с примера, вместо "Привет как дела", вывести должно "как дела".
 Пробовал через split выводить, но не получалось проверку, вводил так
if(val.value == "hellow world".split("hello")[1]){
out.innerHTML = val.split("hello")[1];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что

```js
console.log( "hello world".split("hello") );
```

split в принципе правильно написан,
                     но ваше условие сработает только если введут ровно `" world"`

```js
$("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let val = $("input").value;
  
  console.clear();
  console.log( val.split("hello") ); // не находит HeLLo
  console.log( val.toLowerCase().split("hello") ); // найдет
  
  let split = val.toLowerCase().split("hello");
  
  if (split.length == 1) return;
 
  console.log( split[1] );
});

/***/
function $(str) { return document.querySelector(str); }
```

```html
<input value="Бубу! Hello! Дратути!">
<button>test</button>
```

А введут Hello hello heLlo - не сработает. Если это важно, можно решать и через `indexOf()`:

```js
$("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let val = $("input").value;
  let word = "hello";
  
  let index = val.toLowerCase().indexOf(word);
  
  if (index == -1) return;
 
  console.log( val.slice( index + word.length ) );
});

/***/
function $(str) { return document.querySelector(str); }
```

```html
<input value="Hello hello heLlo world!">
<button>test</button>
```

А через [регулярные выражения](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html), решается в одну строчку:

`console.log(  ( $("input").value.match(/hello(.*)/i) || [0,''] )[1]  );`

Comment: Очень сложно, я с "$("button").addEventListener" ещё не работал вообще, и не понимаю даже зачем $ ставить в начале, а с addEventlistener работал, но зачем $ не понимаб

Comment: @klausdartant `document.querySelector('button');` — находит и возвращает первый тег `<button>` на странице. Чтобы не писать это каждый раз, создал функцию, которая получает строку - и сама вызывает querySelector(строка). А любое название функции или переменной, может содержать символы `$`, `_`, буквы алфавита, и числа (но не начинаться с числа). Я и по приколу назвал функцию `$` - хотя в реальном коде и правда, не стоит так делать - запутывает) P.s. то же самое и с input, вместо $ — можно было `let val = document.querySelector("input").value;`

Comment: Мне split помог, но спасибо что объяснил. Мне лишь нужно искать текст, не не цифру или буквы)